# Can't assign parameter reference value to a new variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, actions-on-google

```
const bobS = new Details("Bob", "Smith", "bob@smith.com");
const janeD = new Details("Jane", "Doe", "jane@doe.com");

function Details(first, last, email) {
    this.firstName = first;
    this.lastName = last;
    this.email = email;
}    

app.intent('2.1 - Our People - person', (conv, params) => {
    let person = params.person;
    conv.close(person.lastName);
});
```

When I run the code above in the Google assistant simulator, the intent assigns the reference value of bobS whenever I mention his name. In theory, it should output Bob's last name, but I'm presented with this very generic error:

> "Failed to parse Dialogflow response into AppResponse"

The weird thing is that when I was testing it without assigning the parameter value to a variable, it works fine.

```
const bobS = new Details("Bob", "Smith", "bob@smith.com");
const janeD = new Details("Jane", "Doe", "jane@doe.com");

function Details(first, last, email) {
    this.firstName = first;
    this.lastName = last;
    this.email = email;
}    

app.intent('2.1 - Our People - person', (conv, params) => {
    conv.close(bobS.lastName);
});
```

I'm pretty sure I'm just not assigning the reference value of params.person to a variable correctly. Can anyone help me out? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I know nothing of google assistant, and might be a stupid question - but have you confirmed params.person is defined? Seems to me most likely is that it's failing on undefined.

Comment: Sounds like something crashes. Can you check server logs.

Comment: @ScottAllen It's defined because when I output params.person it returns bobS, it even gives the same result when I output person. It just fails to output whenever I try to retrieve a property

Comment: @NickFelker server logs are very uniformative with the Google Assistant, the most info it tells me is was the error above, and Error code 200

Comment: But there's probably some sort of function error that should show up. `200` is not an error code.